# PasswordBox PasswordHelper multibinding

Tags: wpf, multibinding, passwordbox, imultivalueconverter

In WPF the `Password` property of a `PasswordBox` is not a `DependencyProperty` so I can't bind to it directly. As a workaround I am using this `PasswordHelper` from https://www.wpftutorial.net/PasswordBox.html which attaches a `PasswordHelper.Password` to the `PasswordBox` so I can bind to it.

To prevent the password from staying in the `DataContext` as plain text I would like to use a converter which generates a salted hash of the password before saving it to the `DataContext`. As I need to save both the salt and the salted hash to the `DataContext` I am using a `MultiBinding` and  a `IMultiValueConverter` converter `StringToSaltedHashConverter`.

My problem is that the `Password` and `PasswordSalt` properties of my `DataContext` are not getting updated when I fill the `PasswordBox`. I have checked with Snoop and both the `Password` and `PasswordHelper.Password` properties of the `PasswordBox`are changing accordingly to what I type. Also my `StringToSaltedHashConverter` is being called and I am returning the correct values.

I have some other bindings on this form (username, first name, last name, gender...) and they all work fine. This is the only one that is not updating.

**¿Why is my `DataContext` not getting updated?**

XAML:

```
<PasswordBox x:Name="Password"
             Style="{DynamicResource PasswordBoxStyle1}"
             local:PasswordHelper.Attach="True">
    <local:PasswordHelper.Password>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource StringToSaltedHashConverter}"
                      Mode="OneWayToSource">
            <Binding Path="Password" />
            <Binding Path="PasswordSalt" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </local:PasswordHelper.Password>
</PasswordBox>
```

Code behind:

```
public class StringToSaltedHashConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string str = value as string;
        string salt = Hash.CreateSalt();
        string hash = Hash.CreateHash(str, salt);
        object[] vs = { hash, salt };
        return vs;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you going to solve with your converter? Just for having the plain password only in one place in memory (DependencyProperty) - Do you think that is 50% more secure than having it in two places (+DataContext)?

Comment: @deiviz: Did you change the type of the `Password` property to `object[]`? You cannot set a `string` property to an array.

Comment: @mm8 No, I did not change the type of the `Password` property. The `PasswordHelper.Password` is converted back to two properties of the `DataContext`(`Password` and `PasswordSalt`). That is why there is an `object[]`.

Comment: @deiviz: You can't set a `string` propert to an `object[]`. That's your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way to go. `PasswordHelper` class and their likes should be banned from the internet. The `PasswordBox.Password` property is not bindable for a very good reason which is well documented. Accessing this property will create a plain text `string` representation which can be effordlessly retrieved with free tools e.g. Microsoft Process Explorer.

> When you get the Password property value, you expose the password as plain text in memory. To avoid this potential security risk, use the SecurePassword property to get the password as a SecureString.
>
> Setting this property to null causes the underlying password to be set to Empty.

You even store the plain salt value in memory - I really hope this is neither a commercial nor a public application. You have absolutely no control when the Garbage Collector will remove any value from the memory. Since `String` is an immutable type, it is very likely that multiple copies of the user's password will remain public in memory.

Recommended authentication in a Windows environment is to use the Windows User Authentication API.

You should at least clear the `PasswordBox.Password` property, by setting it `null`.

Encryption should not be done in the view.

**And please, write responsible code! User data is not *your* data!**

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <PasswordBox x:Name="PasswordBox" />
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.PasswordBox.PasswordChanged += OnPasswordChanged;
  }

  private void OnPasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    (this.DataContext as ViewModel).Password = this.PasswordBox.SecurePassword;
  }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
pucblic class ViewModel
{
  private Model Model { get; }

  private SecureString password;
  public SecureString Password
  {
    private get => this.password;
    public set
    {
      this.password = value;
      OnPasswordChanged();
    }
  }

  private void OnPasswordChanged()
  {
    // Hash password in the model e.g. to compare it to a hashed database value
    this.Model.TryLogin(this.Password);
  }
}
```

**Model.cs**

```
public class Model
{
  public bool TryLogin(SecureString password)
  {  
    IntPtr unmanagedString = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(password);
    string hashedPassword = HashPassword(Marshal.PtrToStringUni(unmanagedString));

    return PasswordIsValid(hashedPassword);
  }

  private string HashPassword(string unsecurePassword)
  {
    // Hash algorithm
  }
}
```

Comment: Converter direction: with OneWayToSource-Mode then only the ConvertBack method will be called. Why should he implement the other method?

Comment: I read it like he's binding the `PasswordBox.Password` property to the evil `PassswordHelper`. The binding direction is wrong since the helper is the target.

Comment: Why would you write back to this property instead of clearing it by setting it to `null`?

Comment: Yes, and the binding direction is OneWayToSource => PasswordHelper.Password property back to the ViewModel property.

Comment: Yes, you are right. He didn't even cleared the `PasswordBox`. I will remove the binding hint.

Answer (score 0):

Before I need the password from a `PasswordBox` the User will tell me that he has finished with input by pressing a button.

The best option for me is to use the `CommandParameter` of the `Button` with the `LoginCommand`:

```xml
<StackPanel
        Width="300"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Label Content="Username:" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Username}" />
    <Label Content="Password:" />
    <PasswordBox PasswordChanged="PasswordChanged" />
    <StackPanel
            Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button
                Name="LoginButton"
                Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"
                Content="Login" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

View code

```cs
private void PasswordChanged( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    LoginButton.CommandParameter = ( sender as PasswordBox ).SecurePassword;
}
```

ViewModel Command

```cs
Login = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask( async ( SecureString password, CancellationToken cancellationToken ) =>
{
    var loggedIn = await AuthenticationService.LoginAsync( Username, password, cancellationToken );
    ...
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to thank everyone for your answers and insighful comments. You made me realize that I should not be using a `PasswordHelper` and that I should not be trying to bind to the password at all.

Just in case anyone is having a similar problem with a `MultiBinding` not properly updating the `DataContext`, this can be fixed by adding the `OneWayToSource` mode to each of the bindings inside the `MultiBinding`.

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource StringToSaltedHashConverter}" 
              Mode="OneWayToSource">
    <Binding Path="Password"
             Mode="OneWayToSource" />
    <Binding Path="PasswordSalt"
             Mode="OneWayToSource" />
</MultiBinding>
```